# How can I connect local db to my Android app locally?

Tags: java, android, mysql, database-connection

I created a local db. How can I connect it to my app?

With this `public static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://localhost:8888/phpmyadmin/tbl_export.php?db=androiddb&table=androiddb&server=1&target=&single_table=TRUE#PMAURL-1:tbl_structure.php?db=androiddb&table=androiddb&server=1&target=&token=e3685a7b51239eb1312ab983d78e5a7b";` in config.java db is not connected....

I hope that you can help me!

Thank you in advance everybody!

Here are my .java classes.

LoginActivity.java:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //Defining views
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private AppCompatButton buttonLogin;

    //boolean variable to check user is logged in or not
    //initially it is false
    private boolean loggedIn = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //Initializing views
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

        buttonLogin = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

        //Adding click listener
        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //In onresume fetching value from sharedpreference
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        //Fetching the boolean value form sharedpreferences
        loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);

        //If we will get true
        if(loggedIn){
            //We will start the Profile Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    private void login(){
        //Getting values from edit texts
        final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        //Creating a string request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.LOGIN_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //If we are getting success from server
                        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase(Config.LOGIN_SUCCESS)){
                            //Creating a shared preference
                            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = LoginActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                            //Creating editor to store values to shared preferences
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                            //Adding values to editor
                            editor.putBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, true);
                            editor.putString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, email);

                            //Saving values to editor
                            editor.commit();

                            //Starting profile activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }else{
                            //If the server response is not success
                            //Displaying an error message on toast
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //You can handle error here if you want
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                //Adding parameters to request
                params.put(Config.KEY_EMAIL, email);
                params.put(Config.KEY_PASSWORD, password);

                //returning parameter
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Adding the string request to the queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Calling the login function
        login();
    }
}
```

Config.java:

```
public class Config {
    public static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://localhost:8888/phpmyadmin/tbl_export.php?db=androiddb&table=androiddb&server=1&target=&single_table=TRUE#PMAURL-1:tbl_structure.php?db=androiddb&table=androiddb&server=1&target=&token=e3685a7b51239eb1312ab983d78e5a7b";

    //Keys for email and password as defined in our $_POST['key'] in login.php
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

    //If server response is equal to this that means login is successful
    public static final String LOGIN_SUCCESS = "success";

    //Keys for Sharedpreferences
    //This would be the name of our shared preferences
    public static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "myloginapp";

    //This would be used to store the email of current logged in user
    public static final String EMAIL_SHARED_PREF = "email";

    //We will use this to store the boolean in sharedpreference to track user is loggedin or not
    public static final String LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF = "loggedin";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using an emulator you can replace "localhost" with "10.0.2.2". But if you need to test it on real device, than you need a hosting or u can connect with tethering.

Comment: ok, now i try with emulator...but i don't export any file from phpmyadmin? it is correct how i am doing?

Comment: if you can make a success request from your browser, then you can do exact same with android. Because it just a "client" :)

Comment: there is connection because when i click on "login" toast say me "username or password is not correct" but in db i created a field "ciccia" and another field "ciccia" i don't know why is not correct

Comment: for request to webservice, i personally prefer using library called retrofit. It's more simple safe thread.